# Covariance between functions of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $Y,X_1,X_2,...$ are random variables (not necessarily i.i.d.) with expectation $0$ and variance $1$, and suppose that
$$Cov(X_n,Y)<\frac{1}{n} $$
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Given a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $||f||_{\infty}\le 1$, can we bound
$$Cov(f(X_n),Y) $$
other then the trivial bounds
$$|Cov(f(X_n),Y)|\le \sqrt{Var(f(X_n))\cdot Var(Y)}? $$

Answer (score 0):

In general I think not. Consider $X$ and $Y$ whose joint distribution is given by the following table with $x+y+z=1$, $0<a<b$ and $r$ a given covariance between $X$ and $Y$:

\begin{array}{l l | c c c }
&&&Y& \\
\hline 
& P(X=x,Y=y)  & -c & 0 & c \\ 
\hline
 & b &   0 & x/2 & 0 \\
\hline
X & a &  z/2 & 0 & y/2 \\ 
\hline
   & -a & y/2 & 0 & z/2 \\
\hline
  & -b & 0 & x/2 & 0  \\
\end{array}

Take $z=0$, $x=\epsilon$, and $y=1-\epsilon$. It is straightforward to show that with $c=\sqrt{[1/(1-\epsilon)]}$ and $a=r/[cy]$, $Cov(X,Y)=r$, and $Var(X)=Var(Y)=1$, where $Var(X)=1$ is achieved by taking $b$ appropriately. Let $f(x)=(1/a)x$ for $x\in [-a,a]$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. $\|f\|_\infty=1$.  It follows that $Cov(f(X),Y)=c(y-z)=(1-\epsilon)\sqrt{[1/(1-\epsilon)]}$, which doesn't depend on $r$ at all, and can be taken to be arbitrarily close to 1. 1 is clearly the upperbound in this example by Cauchy-Schwarz.